# T-SQL: Get a tab-separated list of column names in a table - What's wrong with my example?

Tags: t-sql

This SQL returns a comma-separated list of column names for the table 'MyTable'

```
DECLARE @colnames VARCHAR(max);

SELECT
    @colnames = COALESCE(@colnames + ',', '') + column_name
FROM
    CORP_MLR_Rebates.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    table_name = 'MyTable';

SELECT @colnames;
```

Why doesn't the following give me a tab-separated list the same columns? Instead, it is space-separated.

```
DECLARE @colnames VARCHAR(max);

SELECT
    @colnames = COALESCE(@colnames + char(9), '') + column_name
FROM
    CORP_MLR_Rebates.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    table_name = 'MyTable';

SELECT @colnames;
```

Comment: In my testing it does work, I guess it just depends on how you retrieve the results (I have to output the result to a file to get the correct results)

Comment: Thank you! You are correct!  if you write your reply as an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing it does work, I guess it just depends on how you retrieve the results (I have to output the result to a file to get the correct results)

Answer (score 1):

You will likely get spaces using the SSMS GUI. Returning the results as text or to a file will give you tabs; e.g. CHAR(9). Consider these three queries that all do the job:

```
;--== 1. Updatable Variable
DECLARE @colnames VARCHAR(max);

SELECT @colnames = COALESCE(@colnames + CHAR(9), '') + column_name
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c;

SELECT ColNames = @colnames;

;--== 2. Using STRING_AGG
SELECT ColNames = STRING_AGG(c.COLUMN_NAME , CHAR(9))
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c;

;--== 3. Using FOR XML PATH
SELECT ColNames = 
  (SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME+CHAR(9) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c FOR XML PATH(''));
```

**Results:**

[image]

**If we switch to `Results as Text`:**

[image]

**Now we get (note the tabs):**

[image]